# Построчный перевод HTML в XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, парсер, anglesharp

Есть структура в HTML следующего вида:

```
<div class="conditions-group and-logical">

    /*(Здесь расположена структура div'ов используемая для работы пользователя со структурой дерева, из данного примера удалена)*/

    <div class="conditions">

        <div class="condition">

            <div class="metric">
            /*Селект для выбора значения*/
            </div>

        </div>  

        /*Опциальнально в класс conditions может вкладываться ещё один conditions-group с такой же иерархией*/  

    </div>

</div>
```

Необходимо преобразовать в XML следующего вида:

```
<logical-operator>

    <value>and</value>

    <condition>

        <metric>какое-то значение из селекта</metric>

    </condition>

    /*Здесь также опционально может быть вложенный logical-operator с такой же структурой*/

</logical-operator>
```

Проблема заключается в непонимании как правильно считывать и записывать в XML. Сложность именно в том, что `conditions-group` может вкладываться в `conditions-group` и получается, что считывать HTML нужно построчно, проверять какой это класс и формировать XML.

1. Можно ли обойтись без построчнного считывания, буду благодарен, если
   подскажете как.
2. Если считывать построчно, то нужно находить разрыв строки и
   проверять регулярным выражением? Но насколько я знаю, регулярные
   выражения при HTML - парсинге - плохое решение.
3. Как лучше формировать XML в таком случае? Можно ли формировать его
   вглубь? Т.е. спускаться по HTML и также формировать XML, явно не
   указывая закрывающие теги.

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

P.S. Использую (учусь :)) парсер AngleSharp

Comment: Если HTML - валидный XML, то можно написать XSL преобразование. Если уверенности в валидности нет, то HTML Agility Pack в помощь. Регулярки тут точно не нужны.

Comment: @tym32167 буду очень благодарен примеру, как конкретно использовать Agility Pack в данном случае. Также очень много "нелестного" в его пользу слышал, когда выбирал парсер.

Comment: AngleSharp должен точно так же работать. Смысл парсера в том, что он превращает текстовый HTML в объектную структуру, так что в принципе выбор конкретного парсера (HTML Agility Pack или AngleSharp) не так уж и важен.

Comment: @Vlad как обработать сложную структуру в парсере мне и непонятно, пока могу придумать только рекурсивное обращение, что не очень хорошо.

Comment: @МаксимУстелемов: Рекурсивные структуры данных (а у вас именно такие и есть) по идее и нужно обрабатывать рекурсивно. Парсер позволит абстрагироваться от построчного чтения.

Comment: @Vlad Благодарю)